# Why object won't stop moving in Zelle graphics?

Tags: python, move, zelle-graphics

```
from graphics import *
win = GraphWin("Circle Race", 500, 500)

#red circle position
RcenterX = 50
RcenterY = 100
Rright = RcenterX+25
Rleft = RcenterY

# The Red circle
cr = Circle(Point(RcenterX,RcenterY), 25)
cr.setFill('red')
cr.setOutline('black')
cr.draw(win)


if RcenterX<=400:
    win.getMouse()
    cr.move(50 ,0)
elif RcenterX>300:
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()
```

I'm trying to move the red circle 50 pixels after each click, and stop when the right edge of the circle reaches 400.
But it keeps moving after it reaches 400?
How can I make it stop at 400?

Comment: what language/IDE/OS is this? add TAGs so the right people will read this

Comment: it is just python

Answer (score 0):

Two basic changes: your `if` statement needs to be a `while` loop; you need to recalculate `RcenterX`, either by updating it yourself or interrogating your circle object:

```
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin("Circle Race", 500, 500)

# red circle position
RcenterX, RcenterY = 50, 100
Rradius = 25

# The Red circle
cr = Circle(Point(RcenterX, RcenterY), Rradius)
cr.setFill('red')
cr.setOutline('black')
cr.draw(win)

while cr.getCenter().getX() + Rradius/2 < 400:  # right edge stops at 400
    win.getMouse()
    cr.move(50, 0)

win.getMouse()
win.close()
```